# How to see Javascript stack of a website?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I am visiting **CNN**, and they use javascript as we know. They initialize some variables and change it during my visit. How can I watch what values these variables are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and use the `script` tab. You can set breakpoints, step through code and more.

If you are not using FF, you can use [firebuglite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

---

IE8 and above have similar built in dev tools easily accessible by pressing F12.

Chrome and Safari have such built in tools too, and so does the latest version of Opera.

Comment: If he's using Safari or Chrome, they have built-in debuggers.

Comment: you might find it incredulous, but i have been using chrome inspector for 3 motnhs without noticing the 'call stack' on the right hand side. Wow Edit: a second wow, it lists all variables